# Rich Text area support while composing mail from case in lightning

Tags: lightning, email, case

Rich text area support is there when email is drafted from Opportunity detail page.
On case there is no such support and if we create email quick action it does not support rich text area.

Is there any other configuration changes has to be done to get the rich text area support while composing email from case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution for this. 
We need to drag the html body in the quick [image]

This solves it.